# Grails 2.4.4 : How do mock a transient service inside a domain?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, testing

I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days now and I am really stuck and frustrated. I have a domain object with a service which is being used for custom validation. The domain looks like this:

```
class Llama { 
String name
transient myFetcherService

static transients = [
            'myFetcherService'
    ]

static constraints = {
        name validator: { val, obj ->
            if (obj.nameExists(val) == true) {
                //return some error here.
            }
        }
    }

protected boolean nameExists(String name) {
        List<Llama> llamasList = myFetcherService.fetchExistingLlamasByName(name)

        if (llamasList.isEmpty()) {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Now, I have another Service, which simply saves a list of Llama objects. It looks like this:

```
class LlamaFactoryService {

   public void createLlamas(List<String> llamaNames) {
     llamaNames.each { name ->
         new Llama(name: name).save()
     }
   }

}
```

In my test. I keep getting this error:

```
Failure:  createLlamas should create Llammas (com.myLlamaProject.LlamaFactoryServiceSpec)
|  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method myFetcherService on null object
```

I don't understand. In my tests, added a metaClass for the service in the "given" section. When it tries to save, it's telling that the service is null. This is what my test looks like:

```
given:
def myFetcherService = mockFor(MyFetcherService)   
myFetcherService.demand.fetchExistingLlamasByName {def name -> return []}
Llama.metaClass.myFetcherService = myFetcherService.createMock()

when:
service.createLlamas(['Pablo','Juan','Carlos'])

then:
//some validations here....
```

I also tried using metaClass on the method `nameExists()` like:

```
Llama.metaClass.myFetcherService = { def name -> false }
```

, but it gives me the same nullPointerException as the one above. Could someone point me to the right direction? I'm a bit stuck. :(

Thanks in advance for reading and helping.

Comment: add the  relevant tag here whether it is unit or integration test.

Comment: It's a unit test.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using a unit test and the general rule for unit tests is that beans generally aren't created for you, so you'll need to inject them yourself.

(Code edited to reflect the fact I misread the question)
I think you want a testing pattern something like:

```
given:
def mockMyFetcherService = Mock(MyFetcherService) // create the mock
Llama.metaClass.getMyFetcherService = { mockMyFetcherService } // inject the dependency
def returnList = []  // let's just define this here and you can re-use this pattern in other tests more easily

when:
service.createLlamas(['Pablo','Juan','Carlos'])

then:
// tell Spock what you expect to have happen with your Mock - return the List you defined above
3 * mockFetcherService.fetchExistingLlamasByName(_) >> returnList
```

If the injection of the service into the metaClass doesn't work ([suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132363/injecting-a-mock-service-into-a-domain-class-for-a-grails-unit-test)), you could always try using the defineBeans{} closure within the unit test itself (http://www.block-consult.com/blog/2011/08/17/inject-spring-security-service-into-domain-class-for-controller-unit-testing/).

Thus you could try:

```
defineBeans {
  myFetcherService(MockMyFetcherService)
}
```

where `MockMyFetcherService` is defined in the same file that defines the test.  This is the approach [followed here](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/grails-unit-test-filters-with-the-injected-service/):

See [here](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/Interactions) for examples of more Spock interactions.

If you're using Grails 2.4.3 or below you'll need to put CGLIB in BuildConfig.groovy but I see [here](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11535) that it's already done for you in 2.4.4, so you should be ok just to use `Mock(classname)`.

Comment: Works in 2.3.11 also.

Comment: so, I inject the MyFetcherService in the service that's using the domain? Not in the domain where the MyFetcherService is? Never thought of that... I'm using grails 2.4.4. I'll try this out. Thanks for the response.

Comment: doesn't work man. The myFetcherService is used in the domain, not in the service. I got a .MissingPropertyException: No such property: myFetcherService for class LlamaFactoryService. :\

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I misread the question and thought you were using a service within the service, not a service within the domain.  Let me get back to you with another suggestion shortly.

Comment: @CancerMan hope the new suggestions are useful, I'm interested in how either/both work for you as I'm still learning in Grails.